# How simplify css style for tables

Tags: css

I have a css code I want to improve. Actually this code was copy-pasted from Chrome styles inspector. But I'm stuck with trying to simplify it into one rule using nesting to get "clean" styles:

```
.table > thead > tr > th, .table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > th, .table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > th, .table > tfoot > tr > td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Is there a way to make it simplier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In table we find `<th>` and `<td>` in `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` and in above css all the things are targeted so why not simply use this

```
.table th, .table td{
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This will also target all `<th>` and `<td>` in table.

Answer (score 3):

You can omit middle part as you are selecting all parts from table

```
.table th,
.table td {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.table th,
.table td {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

If you wants to target `th` inside `thead` then you can use

```
.table thead th,
.table thead td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Same is with `tbody` and with `tfoot`. If you wants to override something inside them then you can do as follows:

```
.table tbody th,
.table tbody td {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table tfoot th,
.table tfoot td {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}
```